# Opencart get current layout_id

Tags: layout, get, opencart

I have created a custom layout and i planned to hide products only for those custom layout assigned pages.

Is there any way to get current layout id ?

For example, Let's say my custom layout_id is 10, I planned to use some looping like below to hide/show products

```
if (current_layout_id != 10) {
  // Display products
}else {
  // Hide Products
}
```

Answer (score 2):

find layout id of current displayed module page

```
if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) { 
        $route = $this->request->get['route']; 
    } else { 
        $route = 'common/home'; 
    }
    $layout_id = 0;
    if (substr($route, 0, 16) == 'product/category' && isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
        $path = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
        $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryLayoutId(end($path));
    }
    if (substr($route, 0, 16) == 'product/product' && isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
        $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductLayoutId($this->request->get['product_id']);
    }
    if (substr($route, 0, 16) == 'product/information' && isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
        $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformationLayoutId($this->request->get['information_id']);
    }
    if (!$layout_id) { $layout_id = $this->model_design_layout->getLayout($route); }
    if (!$layout_id) { $layout_id = $this->config->get('config_layout_id'); }
```

end of layout id finding